# Backbone.js: pass value to model url

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

My model:

```
var UsersID = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model:Wine,
    url:"api/wines/id"
});
```

My view:

```
var EditUser = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: '.page2',
    render: function (options) {
        //console.log(options.id);
        var wine = options.id;
        //console.log(wine);
        var that = this,
            users = new UsersID({ id:wine });

        users.fetch({
            success: function (users) {
                var template = _.template($('#user-details-template').html(), {users: users.models});
                that.$el.html(template);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

It is not working: data is not received by the model url.

Comment: what are you getting instead? "not working" is very general..

Answer (score 0):

This is my way:

```
users.url = 'api/wines/' + id;
users.fetch({
            success: function (users) {
                var template = _.template($('#user-details-template').html(), {users: users.models});
                that.$el.html(template);
            }
        })
```